# update JTree nodes with a full TreeNode hierarchy instead of update

Tags: java, kotlin, swing, intellij-plugin, jtree

I have a `JTree` that I want to update its node based on a list that I have receiving from remote (some of its data is already in Tree ,so they are some repeatations)

Here is my data model that comes from remote

```kotlin
data class VariableInfo(
    val name: String,
    val type: String,
    val value: String,
    val children: List<VariableInfo>? = null,
)
```

And here is "VariableInfoTreeNode"

```kotlin
class VariableInfoTreeNode(
    private val variableInfo: VariableInfo,
    private val myParentNode: TreeNode?,
) : TreeNode {
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "${variableInfo.name}:${variableInfo.type} ${variableInfo.value}"
    }

    override fun getChildAt(childIndex: Int): TreeNode {
        return _children[childIndex]
    }

    override fun getChildCount(): Int {
        return _children.size
    }

    override fun getParent(): TreeNode? {
        return myParentNode
    }

    override fun getIndex(node: TreeNode?): Int {
        return _children.indexOfFirst {
            if (node is VariableInfoTreeNode) {
                it == node
            } else {
                false
            }
        }
    }

    override fun getAllowsChildren(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun isLeaf(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    private val _children by lazy {
        variableInfo.children?.map {
            VariableInfoTreeNode(it, this)
        } ?: emptyList()
    }

    override fun children(): Enumeration<out TreeNode> {
        return Collections.enumeration(_children)
    }
}
```

I also have a RootNode for containing `VariableInfoTreeNode` nodes

```kotlin
class VariableInfoRootNode:TreeNode{
    private var children= emptyList<VariableInfo>()
    private lateinit var childrenNodes:List<VariableInfoTreeNode>
    init {
        refreshChildTree()
    }
    fun setVariableInfo(variableInfoList: List<VariableInfo>){
        children=variableInfoList
        refreshChildTree()
    }

    private fun refreshChildTree(){
        childrenNodes=children.map {
            VariableInfoTreeNode(it,this)
        }
    }


    override fun getChildAt(childIndex: Int): TreeNode {
        return childrenNodes[childIndex]
    }

    override fun getChildCount(): Int {
        return childrenNodes.size
    }

    override fun getParent(): TreeNode? {
        return null
    }

    override fun getIndex(node: TreeNode?): Int {
        return childrenNodes.indexOfFirst {
            it==node
        }
    }

    override fun getAllowsChildren(): Boolean {
        return true
    }

    override fun isLeaf(): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun children(): Enumeration<out TreeNode> {
        return Collections.enumeration(childrenNodes)
    }
}
```

and here is my MainTreeContainer class

```kotlin
class DebugBoardView : JPanel(GridLayout()) {
    private val rootNode = VariableInfoRootNode()

    private val treeModel = DefaultTreeModel(rootNode)
    private val tree: Tree = Tree(treeModel).apply {
        isRootVisible = false
    }
    
    // I call this method somewhere else and I want 
    // Tree to update itself and does not lose selection and expansion state
    fun onVariablesUpdate(list: List<VariableInfo>) {
        rootNode.setVariableInfo(list)
        treeModel.nodeStructureChanged(rootNode)
    }

    init {
        add(tree)
        //periodically update with same fake data!
        javax.swing.Timer(5000) {
            onVariablesUpdate(fakeInfo)
        }.start()
    }
}
```

my problem is when I call `DebugBoardView::onVariablesUpdate` my tree will updated but all of selected paths and expanded paths will be gone!

How can I fix that?

It's worth to mention that I am developing `Intelij Idea Plugin` so any solution for this platform could be useful too

Comment: `nodeStructureChanged` basically informs the `JTree` that the underlying structure has completely changed, so any expanded or selection information will be discarded.  The expanded state is maintained internally by the `JTree` and the selection via the `TreeSelectionModel`. If you want to maintain this state between updates, you have two basic choices. You either devise a delta update approach which can add/remove/update the nodes between the new and old models or try and restore the expended and selected states after the update - the first will likely produce a nicer UX